# Detect clicked object inside this object in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a sphere that contain a background picture. I have put the camera inside the sphere to do like a panorama when the sphere rotate.

Now I went to detect when user click on the sphere I have do like three js example :

```
            var intersects = ray.intersectObject(sphere);

            if(intersects.length > 0){

                console.log("intersect");
            }
```

Unfortunately this work only if we click on the outer part of the sphere (when the camera is not inside). When I click inside the sphere it's not detected.

Do you have an idea that how I can do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thank to stephomi (https://github.com/stephomi) I have found the solution.

Must set the side proprery of my sphere's material with THREE.DoubleSide.

And now the click is detected inside the sphere.